# Why does 'std::endl' require the namespace qualification when used in the statement 'std::cout << std::endl;", given argument-dependent lookup?

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup

I was looking at the Wikipedia entry on [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup#Type-associated_namespaces), and (on Jan 04, 2014) the following example was given:

```
#include<iostream>

int main() 
{
  std::cout << "Hello World, where did operator<<() come from?" << std::endl;
}
```

... with the following comment:

> Note that std::endl is a function but it needs full qualification,
>   since it is used as an argument to operator<< (std::endl is a function
>   pointer, not a function call).

My thought is that the comment is incorrect (or simply unclear).  I am considering changing the comment to say, instead

> Note that std::endl needs full qualification,
>   because ADL does not apply to the *arguments* of a function call; it
>   only applies to the function name itself.

Am I correct that the Wikipedia comment is incorrect?  Is my proposed change correct?  (I.e., is my understanding of ADL correct in this example?)

Comment: Same reason why `cout` needs namespace qualification.

Comment: @Mehrdad Although, conceivably, if ADL **were** used to lookup names used as *other arguments* to the function, the name could be found using ADL.

Comment: ADL means that the name of the function can be inferred from the arguments, not the other way round.

Comment: @KerrekSB There is a third potential case - that the name of *other* arguments can be inferred from *some* argument.  I (think I) know that this is *not* how ADL works; hence my suggested edit to the Wikipedia article.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: Why would you think that? [basic.lookup.argdep] is pretty clear I think: "other namespaces [for the name of the *postfix-expression*...] may be searched [...] These modifications to the search depend on the types of the arguments".

Comment: @KerrekSB Perhaps this needs to be another question, but is it *true* that `namespace Foo { class A{}; class B{}; void f(A, B){} }` followed by `Foo::A a; f(a, B());` will correctly locate the name `B`?  (This would be ADL successfully locating the type of an argument to a function call within a namespace, given another argument to the same function whose type is known to be defined in that namespace - if I understand this correctly.)

Answer (score 10):

There's nothing wrong about what Wikipedia says.

```
std::cout << "Hello World, where did operator<<() come from?" << std::endl
```

is equivalent to the following (assuming `operator<<` is implemented as a free function)

```
operator<<(
    operator<<(std::cout, "Hello World, where did operator<<() come from?"),
    std::endl)
```

which clearly requires namespace qualification for both `cout` and `endl` because this is **argument-dependent** lookup (of the function), not *"argument lookup"*.
The arguments determine the function to be called, not the way around.

Comment: Good point.  The nestedness, when spelled out, makes clear that the `std::endl` is the **only** argument in `namespace std` for the *first* call to `operator<<`, and hence it is necessary to trigger ADL.  However: isn't it then true that the comment, appearing in Wikipedia, *(std::endl is a function pointer, not a function call)*, is irrelevant (and therefore misleading)?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: I suppose I could agree it's slightly misleading, because if there was a `std::get_endl()` function that returned `std::endl` it would be a function call, but that would be irrelevant to the whole ADL issue. It's kind of a roundabout way to think about it so it's not common to interpret it that way but if you do I guess it is confusing. What you said certainly isn't wrong so maybe go ahead and change it?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum: I think what Wikipedia meant to do is to *counter* the possible argument, *"But `endl(std::cout)` doesn't require namespace qualification!"*, to which the answer is *"`endl` here is a function call, not a function pointer"*. It makes sense in that context, but if you read it literally I can see why it would be misleading.

Answer (score 3):

Both the original phrasing and your phrasing are correct.

`std::endl` **is** a function. [C++03 spec section 27.6 [lib.iostream.format]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/wp/html/oct97/lib-iostreams.html#lib.iostream.format):

> **Header `<ostream>` synopsis**

```
namespace std {
template <class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT> >
class basic_ostream;
typedef basic_ostream<char> ostream;
typedef basic_ostream<wchar_t> wostream;
template <class charT, class traits>
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& endl(basic_ostream<charT,traits>& os);
...
```

In this context, the `std::endl` function (or more precisely, the function pointer into which it decays) is being passed as an argument to `operator<<`. Since it is an argument, ADL does not apply.

Comment: If so, I think that the statement, in Wikipedia, `(std::endl is a function pointer, not a function call)`, is irrelevant to ADL and hence misleading.  I'd like to remove it.

Comment: It is not technically wrong... But I agree it seems like irrelevant, and potentially misleading, detail. So I would say go for it.

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia entry is correct.  The fact that one of `operator<<`'s operands is in the `std` namespace causes name lookup to include declarations of `operator<<` from namespace `std` in the candidate-declarations set fed to overload resolution.

Comment: Note that I am asking not about the lookup of the *function declaration*, but instead the lookup of *another argument* to the function.  In other words, because *at least one* argument is in `namespace std`, conceivably ADL could be used to look into that namespace to locate *other* arguments to the same function.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum That would be ~function-dependent lookup~ for argument names, not argument-dependent lookup for function names.

Comment: Therefore, I'd think my suggested change is correct - according to this reasoning.  Perhaps I don't understand.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum I think both your changed version and the wikipedia version are correct.  If I were after improving it I'd say what I said above, that the namespaces of all supplied arguments are searched for overload candidates (and perhaps add that since no arguments are supplied for `endl`, it needs a qualification or `using`).