# Why does endl(std::cout) compile

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup

Surprisingly the below code compiles and runs without error on a variety of compilers and versions.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    endl(std::cout);
    return 0;
}
```

[Ideone link](http://ideone.com/pzWazP)

How does it compile? I am sure there is no `endl` in global scope because a code like

```
std::cout << endl;
```

would fail unless `using` is used or else you need `std::endl`.

Comment: Similar to [Interesting behavior of compiler with namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25976267/1708801)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This behavior is called [argument dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) or Koenig lookup. This algorithm tells the compiler to not just look at local scope, but also the namespaces that contain the argument's type while looking for **unqualified** function call.

For ex:

```
namespace foo {
  struct bar{
    int a;
  };

  void baz(struct bar) {
    ...
  }
};

int main() {
  foo::bar b = {42};
  baz(b);  // Also look in foo namespace (foo::baz)
  // because type of argument(b) is in namespace foo
}
```

---

About the piece of code referred in question text:

`endl` or `std::endl` is declared in `std` namespace [as following](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl):

```
template< class CharT, class Traits >
std::basic_ostream<charT,traits>&     endl( std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os );
```

or

```
std::ostream& endl (std::ostream& os);
```

And `cout` or `std::cout` is [declared as](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout)

```
extern std::ostream cout;
```

So calling `std::endl(std::cout);` is perfectly fine.

Now when one calls just `endl(std::cout);`, because the type of argument `cout` is from `std namespace`, unqualified supposedly a function `endl` is searched in `std` namespace and it is found succesfully and confirmed to be a function and thus a call to qualified function `std::endl` is made.

---

Further reading:

1. [GOTW 30: Name Lookup](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/030.htm)
2. [Why does 'std::endl' require the namespace qualification when used in the statement 'std::cout << std::endl;", given argument-dependent lookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926217/why-does-stdendl-require-the-namespace-qualification-when-used-in-the-statem)

Answer (score 3):

It is the way the stream manipulators work.
Manipulators are functions that passed to operator << as arguments. Then within the operator they are simply called.

So you have function declared like

```
template <class charT, class traits>
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& endl(basic_ostream<charT,traits>& os);
```

and you pass its pointer to operator <<. And inside the operator that declared something like

```
ostream& ostream::operator << ( ostream& (*op)(ostream&));
```

the function is called.like

```
return (*endl )(*this);
```

Thus when you see record

```
std::cout << std::endl;
```

then `std::endl` is function pointer that is passed to the `operator <<` as argument.

In the record

```
std::endl( std::cout );
```

namespace prefix before name `endl` may be omitted because in this case the compiler will use the Argument Dependent Lookup. Thus this record

```
endl( std::cout );
```

will compile successfully.

However if to enclose the function name in parentheses then ADL is not used and the following record

```
( endl )( std::cout );
```

will not compiled.

Comment: I think the question is about why `std::` is not required on the function-call form

Comment: @Matt McNabb I reread the post and it seems that you are right.:)